# What does "clobbers" mean in the context of LLVM's memory dependence analysis

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, ssa

I am new to LLVM and i am currently working on something involving memory dependence analysis. Reading the docs i find the term "clobber" is used quite heavily. Now, i do understand what a clobbered register is in terms of e.g inline assembler, but its usage in the LLVM docs is confusing me.

For instance, in https://llvm.org/docs/MemorySSA.html it mentions:

> The operands of a given MemoryAccess are all (potential) clobbers of said MemoryAccess, and the value produced by a MemoryAccess can act as a clobber for other MemoryAccesses...

or

> The store to %a is clearly not a clobber for the store to %b. It would be the walker’s goal to figure this out, and return liveOnEntry when queried for the clobber of MemoryAccess 2.

or

> If you choose to make your own walker, you can find the clobber for a MemoryAccess by...

Also, in this (short) [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdxWmryoHak), on 0:38 he talks about "things that a Store clobbers", and on 0:53 about Load operand being "whatever the Alias Analysis says clobbers it".

I am not sure how to make sense of this usage of the term and i would appreciate any pointers to the right direction.

Comment: The store to %a is clearly not a clobber for the store to %b. In this context I think its mean that store to %a will not overwrite anything which on store to %b is depending on so in this sense store to %b is independent of store to %a. I could be wrong here tho.